# Taking JSON output of AWS MySQL query and surfacing as DataTable on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have successfully connected a web page through AWS API Gateway to a Lambda function to call a SQL query on an Aurora Serverless MySQL database. I am just passing the full return JSON (in string form) to the web page and it appears, for example, as follows:

[image]

Depending on the query, the columns may be different. I would like to be able to take the response output and visualize it with a DataTable on the website. Is there a way to create the DataTable dynamically, presumably by accessing specific keys within the JSON object (not in string-form)?

Disclaimer: I have very little experience with JavaScript/jQuery/JSON format beyond this.

**Update**

I have updated my code so that the output is now displayed in two text boxes (my goal is to get a list of column names and corresponding data and dynamically build a DataTable depending on query results). Image below shows the column headers in top text box and a single value from the records dict in the JSON. Sample code is below.

[image]

```
var DisplayQuery;
(function($) {
  DisplayQuery = function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '***',
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("access-control-allow-origin", "*")
            },
      data: JSON.stringify({
        "sqlStatement": $('#sql-placeholder').val()
      }),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(response) {
        var colLabels = [];
        for (i = 0; i < response.sqlStatementResults[0].resultFrame.resultSetMetadata.columnMetadata.length; i++) {
          colLabels.push(response.sqlStatementResults[0].resultFrame.resultSetMetadata.columnMetadata[i].name)
        };
        $('#test-box-1').text(JSON.stringify(colLabels));
        $('#test-box-2').text(JSON.stringify(response.sqlStatementResults[0].resultFrame.records[0]));
      },
      error: function ajaxError(error) {
        console.error('Error in SQL request');
      }
    })
  }
}(jQuery));
```

Corresponding elements in my index.html are below. I have not yet created an element for the DataTable that I would like to create here.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <p class= "test-box-class" id="test-box-1"><i>This is a test box for database query connection</i></p>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
   <p class= "test-box-class" id="test-box-2"><i>This is a test box for database query connection</i></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post some code

Comment: @ArunmainthanKamalanathan I have posted some additional information based on progress so far

Comment: are you talking about this datatables https://datatables.net/manual/installation

Comment: @ArunmainthanKamalanathan I believe so... I'm not entirely sure I suppose, I was trying to configure my web page with Bootstrap and I saw this: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4 -- as long as I can surface query results dynamically in a table on the page with a CSV export option that is fine with me! I assumed this DataTable format provided for these things to be done easily.

Comment: The key is primarily that the columns are subject to change depending on the query specified.

Comment: posted my answer, you can dynamically set the column names.

Comment: Thank you! I think I solved this issue just by dissecting my JSON -- I tried to use your code because it's simpler but I got an error -- I will still accept your answer for now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use data table. you need to first declare a div in your html where you want to display the data table.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="data-table-container"></div>
</div>
```

then in your jquery code, initialise the DataTable

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '***',
  success: function (response) {

    // format the column labels to [{data: 'Column Name 1'}]
    const colLabels = response.sqlStatementResults[0].resultFrame.resultSetMetadata.columnMetadata.map(value => {
      return {
        data: value
      }
    })

    $('#data-table-container').DataTable({
      data: JSON.stringify(response.sqlStatementResults[0].resultFrame.records),
      columns: colLabels
    })

  },
  error: function ajaxError(error) {

  }
})
```

here is the documentation
https://datatables.net/manual/data/